# com.example.ShowListItems is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fill list which is in another activity using current activity but its giving error:

`com.example.ShowListItems` is not an enclosing class

Here is code:

```
ListAdapter adapterD = new SimpleAdapter(ShowListItems.this, shipmentListDetail, 
    R.layout.list_items_d, new String[]{"id", "controlnumber", "clientcn", 
    "chargeableweight", "totalpieces"}, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.controlno, R.id.clientcn, 
    R.id.chargeableweight, R.id.totalpieces});

lv.setAdapter(adapterD);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ShowListItems.this
```

here's the problem you're trying to access the current activity from ShowListItems, but the class ShowListItems doesn't contain the current activity for sure, but I'm not sure what you mean by this piece, clarify please.

Comment: Yes, its mistake, but i don't know how to access other activity which resides in same package, i used .class but didn't worked.

Comment: why it doesn't work? show me, maybe we can find a solution together.